# Reverse digits of an integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, reverse

How do we reverse a number in javascript?

Comment: So... what's your question exactly?

Comment: `num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an array for reversing a number with:

- Save the sign
- Get the absolute value
- Convert it to string
- Split the string
- Reverse the array
- Join the array
- Convert to number
- Apply the saved sign

```js
var value = -123;
    sign = value < 0 ? -1 : 1,
    reversed = Math.abs(value).toString().split('').reverse().join('') * sign;

console.log(reversed);
```